# Recycler View not loading items always. I am trying to set items from firebase into recycler view. It is showing perfectly but not always

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    package tq.tech.pubgkit
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
    
    class Users_registered : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_registered)
        var loadimg = findViewById(R.id.loading)
        var loadtxt = findViewById(R.id.loadtxt)
        val users = ArrayList()
        lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userlist);
    
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        this
        )
        var firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        var dbrefer = firebase.getReference()
        var ref = dbrefer.child("Registered")
    
        loadimg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loadtxt.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
        users.clear()
        for (i in data.children) {
        val name = i.child("name").getValue().toString()
        val count = i.child("count").getValue().toString()
        users.add(User(name, count))
        loadimg.visibility = View.GONE
        loadtxt.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        }
    
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    
    
        })
        val adapter = User_Adapter(users, this)
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        }
    
        //Adapter
    
        package tq.tech.pubgkit
    
    
        import android.content.Context
        import android.view.LayoutInflater
        import android.view.View
        import android.view.ViewGroup
        import android.widget.TextView
        import android.widget.Toast
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    
    
    
        class User_Adapter(val userList: ArrayList, mContext: Context) : 
        RecyclerView.Adapter(){
    
        var context = mContext
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.user,
        parent,
        false
        )
    
        
        return ViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItems(userList[position])
        }
    
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return userList[position].regname.hashCode().toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return userList.size
        }
    
    
    
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
        val name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username) as TextView
        val count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.count) as TextView
    
    
        fun bindItems(user: User) {
        name.text = user.regname
        count.text = user.regcount
    
    
        }
        }
    
    
        }
```

Comment: `It is showing perfectly but not always` So, it shows sometimes and not all the times?

Comment: yes. Exactly like that.

Comment: I tried many ways but no use.

Comment: This probably depends on external parameters like internet connection, or provider

Comment: The recycler view activity loads when I click on a button. Sometimes I want to click the button more that 10 times to view the data in the recycler view.

Comment: No data fetch from firebase perfectly. I make sure that by toasting the values.